# Lots of errors using PRAW

Tags: python, reddit

I run the code and it gives me a bunch of errors like "invalid_grant error processing request". In my actual code my id's and passwords are set correctly. What am i doing wrong?

```
import random
import praw

jokes = open('jokelist.txt').read().splitlines()
joke = ''

#Sets up base of bot
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='',
                             client_secret = '',
                             username = 'JokeMeBot',
                             password = '',
                             user_agent = 'JokeMeBot by /u/Tawkins')


#sets the subreddit
subreddit = reddit.subreddit('dadjokes')

#how to call the bot
keyword = '!JokeMe'
#Checks if the keyword is in the subreddit
for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
    if keyword in comment.body:
#sets to a random joke and posts
        joke = random.choice(jokes)
        comment.reply(joke)
        print('posted')
    else:
        print("oops")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the praw documentation:

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/authentication.html#script-application

> Note
>
> If the following exception is raised, double check your credentials,
>   and ensure that that the username and password you are using are for
>   the same user with which the application is associated:
>
> OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request

So I would double check your credentials and see if that solves it. 
Remember that the username is your reddit account name, not the bot's name.